# Finding it out how a file was deleted in Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a certain image in my Google Cloud Storage Bucket but it was gone w/out us knowing how it was deleted. When I checked the activity logs.. All I can see is "updated". By the way I see it, updated will be the status whether the files is deleted or created. So how can I check this? I want to know at least when it was deleted

Answer (score 2):

In order to see audit logs for Cloud Storage you have to first enable them.

To enable them in the console go to the [IAM & Admin -> Audit Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit) and than by selecting Google Cloud Storage you will see on the right side of the screen under `LOG TYPE` different services  which you can enable or disable audit logging for. Please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console) documentation where the procedure is described.

After the Cloud Storage logs are enabled you can see all the activity by going in the console to [ACTIVITY](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity) and under `Activity types` select `Data access`. After this you will be able to see the operations on the bucket (considering you have [the right permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#data-access) to see those).

Comment: Can you give me an example on how the log should look like when I deleted a file in my GCS?

Comment: Name of the activity should be `Delete object`

Comment: Too many activity logs there under `Activity Types: data access`.  But could not find any way to filter by `activity: delete object`. Is there any better way?